# How to get a total number of hours in Ruby on Rails app and show it on the index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an app where the user can log his working hours after he finished his shift. The app is developed in Ruby on Rails 4.I used the scaffold  method, so it generated the necessary methods for create, read, update, delete. The fields are hours_worked:number overtime:boolean and date:datetime, for now, I plan to expand it later with more functionality, with user login and some other stuf. The model is empty, I did used the rake db:migrate method. Now I know that you can use the count method, as is shown on the official site for active record. I don't have the idea how to get the total number of hours worked and show it on the index page. Consider that I just started learning Rails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to share code with us here.  We need to know about your User model, the fields on it and what you need to sum up (is it on the user model? some other model?).  Share information with us.

Comment: Have a look at [`ActiveRecord::Calculations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is best used with the `Timers` gem.

https://github.com/celluloid/timers

In your `Sessions#new` method, you'd want to initialize a variable to keep track of the current time. And then every so often, you'd use one of the methods in the gem to update the current time. You could then subtract the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without any info on how you are actually logging the info, or seeing any of your code. However if you are just looking for general suggestions you could just save start and stop timestamps and compare them. Or ask the user to input time worked. There are probably a thousand different ways to do this. Please be more specific on what exactly you need help with.